# A bundle with Infinite Loop on Equinox OSGI Framework

Tags: osgi, equinox, osgi-bundle

I have a bundle that is running with infinite loop on Equinox OSGI Framework. Because of this bundle, I am not able to start a new bundle when I run the framework again. How can I stop this bundle in this situation?

Here is the command I type to start the framework:

```
java -jar org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.0.v20130529-1710.jar -console
```

It shows this message infinitely:

```
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
...........
```

Answering this question will also help to answer how to stop an OSGI bundle while it is executing a method, and if that is allowed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your bundle has entered an infinite loop in its `BundleActivator.start` method, and therefore tied up the OSGi callback. Obviously this is not something you should do!! You have no choice but to shutdown the JVM, perhaps forcibly.

Now the problem is to stop the bundle from being started again automatically next time you launch OSGi. The simplest way to ensure this is to delete the "storage" directory where OSGi remembers the list of bundles that were started last time it ran. Unfortunately the storage directory location is subject to a configuration property and you have not specified how you have configured OSGi. The default for Equinox is `configuration/org.eclipse.osgi`, so try deleting that. You could also try running with `-clean`.

Regarding how to stop an OSGi bundle while it is executing a method: you can of course stop a *bundle* and this will cause its `stop` method to execute. You can do whatever you like in that method: in general you should aim to clean up anything you created in the `start` method. However if you have a runaway thread then there is basically nothing you can do, since Java offers no way to kill a thread, it only offers a cooperative `interrupt` method.

OSGi cannot change the fundamental rules of Java, so runaway threads are just as much of a problem in OSGi as they are in any other Java application.

Comment: Thanks Neil...Let's say I have a bundle that provides "Hello World" Message Infinite Times in one of its methods....Now The problem I faced is that i can't call stop() unless this method finishes executing (which is impossible), so how am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Hopefully you already another thread handy from which you can call `stop`. But there's not much point. Just kill the JVM.

Comment: I did killed JVM, and deleted the directory. Everything is fine now. But now I need to demonstrate how to stop a bundle while its running a method. I want to do that in order to see if the process will be fully killed or what will happen.

Comment: So I am going to launch the bundle from another thread, and let the main thread stop the bundle. Agree?

Comment: Yes, I launched the bundle in another thread, and I was able to notice that stopping this bundle, won't stop the thread. Many Thanks. You deserve more votes!

Comment: Threads and bundles have no connection with each other, except for the connection that you create in your activator `start` and `stop` methods.